# How to use the WordPress excerpt

Tags: wordpress

One of my client has very lengthy posts to display due to which take more time to load a single post. He wants me to to show first 500 hundred words and then a link saying 'Load More'. When reader clicks on that link/button, the next 500 words should appear and so on.

Any suggestions ..
Any help with code guideline ..

Comment: What is the code you're currently using or have tried to use?

Answer (score 0):

As it is a post, just insert the '[more tag](http://en.support.wordpress.com/splitting-content/more-tag/)' where ever you want the page to break. You can insert as many as you want on a post.

I must add it's a bit odd having such a long post.

Comment: I am totally fresh in wordpress development so please guide me further, do I have to use 'the_content()' or just <?php the_excerpt();?>. One more thing to use this excerpt function on single post display page which file I should edit to make it work for me on single post page.

Comment: After re-reading your question I am changing my answer, as the_excerpt will not help you much in this instance.